# Need to print second column of a file in output file

Tags: string, unix, awk

Our file has be viewed with samtools. I need to grab only the second column of that so I did

```
./samtools view mybamfile.bam | awk '{ print $2 }' > output.txt
```

You would guess that didn't work .. How should I query to get only the second column my file *mybamfile.bam* if awk is not a good option I'm willing to try anything else!

Comment: Can you give example output from samtools?

Comment: It would have helped if you had shown us your file. Awk separates the file using field separator (default being space or tab).

Comment: That should work but you may need to specify what the delimiter is. Unless you show some data, we can only guess.

Comment: @JaypalSingh true, but if you *only* want to separate on the tab character, you'll need to specify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the output of `./samtools view view mybamfile.bam` is tab delimited, so the field separator for AWK should be set to tab (`-F'\t'`) in order to get the second column.

Try this command:

```
 ./samtools view mybamfile.bam | awk -F'\t' '{ print $2 }' > output.txt
```

Re tab as separator:

If the field separator is not specified AWK will split on "whitepaces" (e.g., space and tab), using `-F'\t'` makes sure it splits *only* on tabs, not spaces. This makes a difference in file that contains both spaces and tabs. E.g,

```
irene adler john moriarty
frank pempleton tim bayliss
```

assume there is a tab between the two names on each line. If the tab character is *not* specified as field separator AWK will see **4** fields per line and column 2 will contain `adler` and `pempleton`. If tab *is* specified as field separator, AWK will only see **2** fields on each line, and column 2 will consist of `john moriatry` and `tim baylis`.

Tested with GNU Awk 3.1.6 under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

awk will by default take the field separator as tab.so your command should work if the field separator is indeed a tab.
May be you can try with :

```
./samtools view mybamfile.bam |cut -f2 -d'\t'
```

Comment: If you don't specify anything AWK will split on space and tab, using `-F'\t'` makes sure it splits *only* on tabs, not spaces.